Mac Mini BIOS interpreting Ctrl+Alt+F2+F3 as power button
Recently, I've been working on an old Mac Mini (late 2014 model) running a fairly basic Debian Bookworm install for certain tasks. It has no X server, just fbcon, and I'm constantly hopping between the TTYs. However, I have a fat finger, and more than once, I have pressed the key combination Ctrl+Alt+F2+F3, which triggers a shutdown, as if I were to press the power button. It hasn't caused any major headaches yet, but I'd like to figure out what is going on before it does.
I'm not aware of anything that may be listening to the keyboard other than fbcon, bash, and btop, as nothing else is running, and there's no graphical environment. I can't find anything on this specific keystroke on the internet, so it probably isn't some default configuration for one of these programs either.
Under journalctl, there are these lines that seem to be helpful, followed by a normal shutdown sequence:
systemd-logind[603]: Power key pressed short.
systemd-logind[603]: Powering off...
systemd-logind[603]: System is powering down.

Testing the same keyboard out on another system (that is not a Mac) with a nearly identical software setup does not have the effect, even with the same keyboard, and with a different, PS2 keyboard. Same thing with my laptop's built-in keyboard. Unfortunately, I do not have another USB keyboard to test the Mac with, and I cannot use the PS2 keyboard on the Mac.
My theory is that the Mac has some weird EFI "feature" that interprets this key combination as a shutdown button, and if this is possible to disable (without using MacOS), I would like to know how.

This question is similar to: Change panel app shortcuts in Linux. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@DrMoishePippik I edited my question to further clarify that I am not using any GUI applications, thanks for the heads-up

What does "not using any GUI application" have to do with the fact that there is a means of changing existing keyboard shortcuts? Do you mean you want a solution that avoids using Debian's built-in GUI for configuration?

@DrMoishePippik I don't have the built in GUI, I have no GUI at all, only the console. The question you've linked is for changing KDE's shortcuts, I do not have KDE installed.
